What is the proper way to convert Task to Task<T>?
I use a library that takes Task<T>, but sometimes I have to pass just Task, which I have to convert to Task<int>. What would be the more efficient/recommended option for converting the task?
Option 1:
Task<int> Convert(Task input)
{
    if (input is Task<int> converted)
        return converted;

    Func<Task<int>> converter = async () =>
    {
        await input;
        return 0;
    };

    return converter();
}

Option 2:
Task<int> Convert(Task input)
{
    if (input is Task<int> converted)
        return converted;

    return input.ContinueWith<int>(_ => 0, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}

Maybe some option 3?
I'm looking for an answer that maximizes compatibility. That means, but is not limited to:

If the input task throws, the same exception with same stacktrace is thrown by the converted task (i.e. no unnecessary wrapping with AggregatedException, no different stacktrace).
If the input task already has some steady state (it's already finished, faulted, etc), then the converted task must have the same state.
I don't want to add unnecessary context switches. That means, for example, if the input task finishes in a specific thread, the converted task should finish ASAP in same thread. That's why I added TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously on option 2, but I'm not sure if that is correct/needed.
The library may use ContinueWith, Wait, etc. Anything that would work if the input task is already typed should also work with the converted task. Also assume that the library may have dependencies on synchronization context, execution context, task scheduler, etc.


The normal return type used in functional programming for when something doesn't return a value is a singleton value, often called Unit.

this  and this seem like related questions. Are the solutions there not working?

Option 1 is close, but if you enable warnings you'll see what the problem with your code is. The efficient (and much simpler) way to write it is as follows:
Task<int> Convert(Task input)
{
    if (input is Task<int> converted)
        return converted;

    static async Task<int> converterHelper(Task input)
    {
        await input;
        return 0;
    };

    return converterHelper(input);
}


Thanks. I understand that the compiler generates a continuation with the "return 0" code. Is that continuation running synchronously? i.e. Does that have the same effect of TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously ?

It kind of depends. Technically, the better code would be await input.ConfigureAwait(false);, if you understand the implications. This version will return on the same context it was called on, but you can force that anyway by using ConfigureAwait on the parent task.

Option 2 have the least overhead, as it doesn't introduce another state machine, but it lacks of error propagation.
So grab this Option 3:
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    private const int DummyResult = 0;

    // Cached successful task, allocated only once.
    private static readonly Task<int> _successfulTask = Task.FromResult(DummyResult);

    // Cached delegate, allocated only once.
    private static readonly Func<Task, int> _dummyContinuation = static (t) =>
    {
        // Propagate cancellation/exception.
        // This will throw original exception without additional wrapping in AggregateException.
        // ('await' basically does the same)
        t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return DummyResult;
    };

    public static Task<int> Convert(this Task input, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (input is Task<int> converted)
            return converted;

        // Save some CPU time and memory if the task is already completed without errors.
        if (input.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            return _successfulTask;

        return input.ContinueWith(
            _dummyContinuation,
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Current);
    }
}


why TaskScheduler.Current?

Because this is the default, that is used when you use any overload that does not have a scheduler in its argument list.

Why are you passing the cancellation token again in the ContinueWith call? If cancellation is requested, isn't sufficient to simply allow input to throw the cancelation exception?

The input may or may not throw the cancellation exception, there is no guarantee. The input may have been created with different cancellationToken.
Passing another cancellationToken allows to cancel the "converted" task.
I've passed it mainly due to convention - asynchronous methods should accept cancellation token as last argument if they can be cancelled.

If input does not throw cancellation exception, then the exception must not be thrown at all. Compatibility is a must-have here, i.e. I don't want a situation where input finishes successfully but the converted task throws.

Ok, just remove cancellationToken argument and use CancellationToken.None instead. Thats all.

The normal return type used in functional programming for when something doesn't return a value is a singleton value, often called Unit.
So, I'd write this extension method:
public static class TaskEx
{
    public static async Task<Unit> ToUnit(this Task task)
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Unit.Default;
    }
}

From the documentation:

When an asynchronous method awaits a Task directly, continuation usually occurs in the same thread that created the task, depending on the async context. This behavior can be costly in terms of performance and can result in a deadlock on the UI thread. To avoid these problems, call Task.ConfigureAwait(false).

Then you can call it like this:
Task task1 = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));

Task<Unit> task2 = task1.ToUnit();

Unit unit = await task2;

Here's an implementation of Unit that you can use:
public readonly struct Unit : IEquatable<Unit>
{
    public static Unit Default => default(Unit);
    public bool Equals(Unit other) => true;
    public override bool Equals(object? obj) => obj is Unit;
    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;
    public override string ToString() => "()";
    public static bool operator ==(Unit first, Unit second) => true;
    public static bool operator !=(Unit first, Unit second) => false;
}


The most concise from I can think of
async Task<int> Convert(Task input)
{
    var wrapped = async () => { await input; return 0; };
    return input is Task<int> converted
        ? await converted
        : await wrapped();
}


Update #1
To avoid unnecessary memory allocation if input is a Task<int>
async Task<int> Convert(Task input)
    => input is Task<int> converted
        ? await converted
        : await ((Func<Task<int>>)(async () => { await input; return 0; }))();


I guess that this implementation allocates memory even in case the input can be cast directly to Task<int>.

@TheodorZoulias Yes, I think you are right. I've added an alternative which inlines the wrapped's definition and call inside the else part.

The alternative wouldn't win a beauty contest though. :-)

@TheodorZoulias yepp, that's an ugly beast ;)
